# QCompleter select data from multiple columns

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcompleter

I'm trying to have a completer complete on a line edit where one puts in some string like "firstname, lastname", which each correspond to one of two columns from a table model (the ultimate goal is for the order to be flexible, but for the moment i just want this running). The current ways i'm trying to go about it is either:

a) merge the results from the two columns into a proxy w a third column that just has firstname,lastname as a discrete string (which is inconvenient if the user puts it in as lastname,firstname. Current implementation doesn't work bc when i try to do setCompletionColumn on the "fake" column it doesn't activate my reimplemented data method. columnCount includes the fake column tho)

b) have a Completer which doesn't filter, with a backend proxymodel whose acceptsrow() filter filters on both first and last (don't know how to do the non-filtering completer - otherwise it's just looking through one column and the popup at the end shows a bunch of first names without the last names)

c) spoof a Tree model and make it so when i put a comma, the model then looks through a "branch" consisting of all people whose first OR last names are (begin with?) the pre-comma string. (i'm just like not sure how to even start on this, it uses the same sort of acceptsrow as b) but idk how to do like separate ~branches~)

this is giving me a headache, and none of these implementations are particularly pleasant. Am I making this too hard on myself and like using the wrong tool, or is it just something i've gotta buckle down into? I can paste some code, but atm i'm wondering if what im doing is even worthwhile.

---

update: code snippets and pix

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIYeF.png)

the red circle is what i'm talking about with multiple firstnames, they correspond to different entries in the table but the completer is limited to one column. In terms of clicking and getting the name of the user i've got that mostly figured out, it's just the format and handling commas.

Here's part of my completer class:

```
 class CustomQCompleter(QCompleter): #dropdown box of suggestions    
    def __init__(self, parent=None,*args):#parent=None):
        self.columnind=0
        super(CustomQCompleter, self).__init__(*args)
        self.parent=parent
        self.setCompletionColumn(self.columnind)
    def pathFromIndex(self,index,role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole): #decides what gets put into selection box
        #print(index)
        model=self.source_model
        return model.data(model.index(index.row(),self.columnind),role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
    def splitPath(self, path):
        self.local_completion_prefix = path #???
        print(path)
        sp=self.local_completion_prefix.split(',')
        if len(sp)>1: #
            print('path split')
            return sp

        return [path]
```

and here's the acceptsrow on my reimplemented proxymodel:

```
def filterAcceptsRow(self, row_num, parent): #input matches if this returns true       
    self.filterString=self.parent().inp.text()
    self.filterList=[i.strip() for i in self.filterString.split(',')]
    l=len(self.filterList)
    while l<2:#easiest way to get thru this atm, clean up later
        self.filterList.append('')
        l=len(self.filterList)
    if self.baseModel is not None:
        model=self.baseModel
    else:
        model = self.sourceModel()  # the underlying model, 

                      # implmented as a python array

    row = [model.data(model.index(row_num,0)),model.data(model.index(row_num,1))] #gets the data for this row from sql model in list format



    #(row[0] starts with fname and row[1] starts w lname) OR vice versa
    tests=[row[0].startswith(self.filterList[i]) and row[1].startswith(self.filterList[1-i]) for i in [0,1]]
    #tests = len(self.filterSet.intersection(set([row[col] for col in self.filterColumns])))==2
   # print(tests)
    return True in tests
```

and ideally it would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: You could explain me better, I understand more what you want, but I confuse your sentence: *the order to be flexible*, What does that mean?. On the other hand you could explain how it should work, I think you are partially indicating this in your options but it is not clear yet.

Comment: I understand that when no text has been selected, a popup appears with the first and last name together, if I select one of the options, should my firstname and lastname be displayed together or should it be displayed?

Comment: @eyllanesc 'order flexible' as in the user should be able to either type 'firstname, lastname' or 'lastname, firstname'. Right now, the popup is being fed from the 2-column table model with the names, and since it can only show one column at a time, the popup box just says the firstnames. What i want is to be able to type someone's name, select their whole name, and be able to return the 2-column name. Right now i have the ID signal from the completer's activate fn, so i should be able to figure out how to get a specific customer ID for a name, now it's just showing and parsing the names right

Comment: What you want is to search using the firstname or lastname and in the popup show both concatenated texts with space, and when you select an item from the QComboBox the QLineEdit must have the concatenated text. I am right?

Comment: You could show your model, besides showing the different scenarios, also some images would help.

Comment: @eyllanesc updated op!

Comment: You could show examples of how it should work with fictitious data, I understand how it should not work but it would be better if you indicate how it would work correctly. Your post has focused a lot on indicating your possible solution but not on your specific objective.

Comment: @eyllanesc how about now?

Comment: Much better, you could add more examples to enrich your question. I have another question. What class does your model belong to?

Comment: @eyllanesc rn it's a sfproxy model sourced from a sqltablemodel, not sure what other examples would better explain

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is to use a proxy where a new role is created that will return the concatenated texts, so that the popup with the concatenated texts is seen, we will establish a custom delegate to the `popup()` of `QCompleter`.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QIdentityProxyModel, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStyledItemDelegate, QCompleter, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QTableView, QStyleOptionViewItem, QStyle
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlTableModel

JoinRole = Qt.UserRole +1

class JoinProxyModel(QIdentityProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, columns, *args, **kwargs):
        QIdentityProxyModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._columns = columns

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == JoinRole:
            texts = []
            for c in self._columns:
                texts.append(self.sibling(index.row(), c, index.parent()).data())
            return ", ".join(texts)
        return QIdentityProxyModel.data(self, index, role)

class JoinDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        opt = QStyleOptionViewItem(option)
        self.initStyleOption(opt, index)
        opt.text = index.data(JoinRole)
        widget = option.widget
        style = widget.style() if widget else QApplication.style()
        style.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, opt, painter, widget)


class JoinCompleter(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, model, columns, parent=None):
        QCompleter.__init__(self, parent)
        # columns: are the columns that are going to concatenate
        proxy = JoinProxyModel(columns)
        proxy.setSourceModel(model)
        self.setModel(proxy)

        self.setCompletionRole(JoinRole)
        self.setFilterMode(Qt.MatchContains)
        self.popup().setItemDelegate(JoinDelegate(self))


def createConnection():
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(":memory:")
    if not db.open():
        QMessageBox.critical(nullptr, QObject.tr("Cannot open database"),
            QObject.tr("Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                        "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                        "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                        "to build it.\n\n"
                        "Click Cancel to exit."), QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return False

    query = QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("create table person (id int primary key, "
               "firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20))")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(101, 'Danny', 'Young')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(102, 'Christine', 'Holand')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(103, 'Lars', 'Gordon')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(104, 'Roberto', 'Robitaille')")
    query.exec_("insert into person values(105, 'Maria', 'Papadopoulos')")

    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)

    w = QWidget()

    lay = QVBoxLayout(w)
    le = QLineEdit()
    view = QTableView()
    model = QSqlTableModel()
    model.setTable("person")
    model.select()

    completer = JoinCompleter(model, [1, 2])
    le.setCompleter(completer)
    view.setModel(model)

    lay.addWidget(le)
    lay.addWidget(view)

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the absence. This gets a lot of the way there, only problems ive encountered r that it doesn't allow for lastname-comma-firstname (tho it allows for lastname input and then choose first name), and i don't know if i've perhaps implemented something wrong, but the delegate doesn't seem to be doing anything for me, i'm still getting a list of first names. Any more ideas? thank you so much for yr help so far :)

Comment: if it bores you don't feel obligated, i'd said it a couple times in a couple different ways in comments but internet doesn't always come across clearly. The delegate class is exactly the same as yours except it's got a print('test') in it, it just never gets activated for some reason. Is there something more you need than the setcompletionrole and setitemdelegate?

Comment: within the paint fn

Comment: ok turns out its something in my implementation, works fine copying and pasting yr code and prints out 'test'. the only thing is figuring out being able to do first,last and last,first

Comment: @user26472 
Plop, you confuse me, explain your new requirement better, besides you do not talk about the delegate since according to comments it works correctly. Give me more examples, do you want the options to exist `Ann, Tyler` and `Tyler, Ann`?

Comment: Ok fixed the issue with the delegate! (i hadn't set the table, since i set a query including the table and i thought that was equivalent :/ ). Ultimately what i'm trying for is for either Ann, Tyler or Tyler, Ann to activate the same entry in the popup (which shows first, last), and not two separate entries pointing to the same underlying db entry.